# SUMIF inside a SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel, sumifs, weighted-average

I have a data set and I am trying to get the weighted average. I am finding the weighted average of credit scores weighted by an unpaid balance for each specific year. I was able to get the sum of all unpaid balances using a SUMIFS statement

```
SUMIFS($E$2:$E$111246,$G$2:$G$111246,">="&DATE(1999,1,1),$G$2:$G$11246,"<="&DATE(1999,12,31)))
```

I now have to use the same date criteria, but I have to find the sum of the products of the cells in E and M for the initial step in getting the weighted average. I thought a SUMPRODUCT would work but I am not really familiar with it and have no idea where to start. Would the SUMIFS be nested in the SUMPRODUCT or the other way around? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
  A    B       C  
2000  700  2/14/1999  
1500  750   1/1/2001  
1700  720   5/6/2000  
3000  680   7/8/1999  
4000  650   8/9/1999
```

In this simplified example, how would I get the total weighted value (Before dividing) of the year 1999? So I would need (2000*700)+(3000*680)+(4000*650) = 6,040,000.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C1:C5)=1999)*(A1:A5*B1:B5))
```

[image]

Your other formula can be simplified to this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($G$2:$G$111246)=1999)*$E$2:$E$111246)
```

Comment: @AndrewCho is there a reason for getting the sum? Using scotts formula, you could directly go for the weighted average: `=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C1:C5)=1999)*A1:A5*B1:B5)/SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C1:C5)=1999)*B1:B5)`?